# Control styling of elements within iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

im not sure if this is possible or not, but im trying to alter the style of elements contained within an iFrame using javascript.

I have tried the following which I believed in theory should work with no luck...

```
<script>
function click() {
window.frames[0].document.getElementById('daLink').style.backgroundColor="#000";
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="click()" >Test</a>
<iframe src="http://www.google.co.uk" width="600" height="400" id="daLink"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will only work if the iFrame Source is on the same domain.
Your code is not working due to the same-origin-policy!

Read more here: [Javascript Security](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Security/)

Comment: I understand what your saying regarding origin policies, but if firebug can alter elements in a webpage, why can't I write a script which can do the same thing?

Comment: with firebug you can only access and edit sites you are on. if you could simply edit content of iframe sources with javascript, you could include a website of a bank, where the user MIGHT be logged in, edit links, let him automatically click something, and so on...

Comment: Is it possible to have an iFrame where you make a copy of the page you are looking to put into the iFrame, then as it's basically unusable from a security point of view (links go nowhere etc)...can you change the elements around?